# What's the best way to prepare for my first half marathon? Is strength and running training enough?

Tags: running-training-plan, half-marathon

I decided to try to do the [super halfs](https://www.superhalfs.com/en/) challenge next year: 5 half marathons in 6 months. The first one (in [Lisbon](https://www.maratonaclubedeportugal.com/en/)) is in 4 months and I'm going to start training.

I've been running once or twice a week, a 5km run and an 11km run. The last competition that I participated I did 10km in 1 hour and 2 minutes (pace of 6'14'), my best personal mark.

My Idea of preparation is:

- Muscle Strength Training three times a week
- three runs a week, alternating between time, speed and distance runs
- I also swim twice a week and would like to keep these workouts

I still don't know how I'm going to do with the diet, it's something I'm going to consult a specialist.

Does this plan make sense?

How did you prepare for your first half marathon?

In your experience is it possible to run 5 races in 6 months or is it too heavy for someone who has never made a half?

Comment: Are you including a day of rest in your plan?  You will likely benefit from one a day or two after your long run each week.

Comment: Yes, I'll do some strength and run trainings at the same day, so I can have at least one day to rest, It's a good idea do it in the day after the long run, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

With four months to go you have plenty of time but you need to gradually build the distance up until you are running 18-20km maybe a few weeks before hand. If you only are going to run three times a week then I would focus on distance and getting that distance further every few weeks. Then as you progress through the half marathons you can begin to work on speed and time. I'd try to run a few more times each week in the build up (eg 5-10km runs in the week x 3 or 4, then a long 11-18km run at the weekend).

I'd look to do one or two 10Km races in the build up to the first half. Gets you back used to pre race nerves etc and you can work on your speed there, maybe try to get below 1h for a 10Km. When I have gone for PBs in half marathons I have always made sure I am comfortable with the pace in a 10Km race beforehand.

Although the distance can seem daunting when you have never run that far before, once you are used to it it is not too much of a strain on the body. If you were attempting 5 full marathons I'd be more concerned. But make sure you make a note of your distance run on your shoes, you may have some very worn out shoes by the end that could injure yourself. If you havent already get some proper running shoes from a proper running shop.

With you 10Km time of 1h2m I'd estimate you'll do the first in 2h10m (although from memory of being there as a tourist Lisbon is not flat so may be slower). Try and have some flat halfs towards the end of the challenge because I bet you could get below 1h50m by the end. Good luck!

Comment: Tks! I was thinking about going on a 14-week training plan; the last week would be the 21k. But make total sense what you say about focusing on distance and working on speed later, although the hills, the route in the Lisbon half is flat. The shoes I'm using to train now has around 200km, but I'll probably get another one for competitions. Thank you for the input!